# Delete a child in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried to remove a child from my firebase database, but the problem is that it gives me an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.example.juang.trainingplan.Objects.Edit.full_name' on a null object reference at
com.example.juang.trainingplan.Edit_athlete$4.onDataChange(Edit_athlete.java:100)
```

The key is removed but the application is closed.

This is the code I use to remove:

```
public class Editar_atleta extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nombre,fecha,categoria,correo, celular;
    Button editar, eliminar;
    String key, entrenador;
    private DatabaseReference database;
    private Task<Void> data;
    private static final String CERO = "0";
    private static final String BARRA = "-";
    public final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final int anio = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editar_atleta);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        key=intent.getStringExtra("llave");
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("ingreso", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        entrenador = preferences.getString("login", "");

        nombre=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_nom_editar);
        fecha=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_fecha_editar);
        categoria=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_categoria);
        correo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_correo_editar);
        celular=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_cel_editar);
        editar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_editar);
        eliminar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_eliminar);

        llenardatos();

        fecha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                obtenerFecha();
            }
        });

        editar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cargardatos();
            }
        });

        eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                eliminar_base();
            }
        });
    }

    private void llenardatos() {

        database =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(entrenador).child(FirebaseReferences.DEPORTISTA_REF).child(key);
        database.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Editar editar= dataSnapshot.getValue(Editar.class);

                nombre.setText(editar.full_name);
                fecha.setText(editar.date_of_birth);
                categoria.setText(editar.category);
                celular.setText(editar.phone);
                correo.setText(editar.email);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }

    private void obtenerFecha(){
        DatePickerDialog recogerFecha = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                final int mesActual = month + 1;

                String diaFormateado = (dayOfMonth < 10)? CERO + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth):String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                String mesFormateado = (mesActual < 10)? CERO + String.valueOf(mesActual):String.valueOf(mesActual);
                fecha.setText(diaFormateado + BARRA + mesFormateado + BARRA + year);
            }

        },anio, mes, dia);
        recogerFecha.show();
    }

    private  void  cargardatos(){
    }

    private void eliminar_base(){
        data =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(entrenador).child(FirebaseReferences.DEPORTISTA_REF).child(key).removeValue();
    }


}
```

This is the basis and the highlighted is what I want to eliminate:
[image: Database]

I clarify that I already tried to use setValue(null) and I still get the same error.

Comment: Please share you `Editar` class code.

Comment: Okay, I'll put the edit class on.

Comment: public class Editar {

    public String date_of_birth;
    public String full_name;
    public String phone;
    public String email;
    public String gender;
    public String category;


    public Editar(){

    }


    public Editar(String full_name, String date_of_birth,String phone,String email, String gender, String category) {

        this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
        this.full_name=full_name;
        this.phone=phone;
        this.email=email;
        this.gender=gender;
        this.category=category;
    }


}

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting, check if the node is not empty:

```
if(!FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(entrenador).child(FirebaseReferences.DEPORTISTA_REF).child(key).empty()) {
data =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(entrenador).child(FirebaseReferences.DEPORTISTA_REF).child(key).removeValue();
}
```

if not, then delete

Comment: @AndréKool Added in the wrong place. Just added in the place it belongs. Thanks